# Convert Lightroom presets (.lrpreset) to Darktable (as .dtstyle)?

Tags: lightroom, darktable, style, import, presets

Apparently, there is no way to import lightroom presets into darktable directly. Would it be possible to convert Lr presets to dtstyle-files?

Darktable comes with Lua support which shouldn't make it too difficult to write a converter. The only trouble is that the picture development functions seem to be different and Darktable's API could be documented better.

Does anybody have an idea how to start with this?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I am considering attempting to build a converter myself as well.

Comment: @Tim No, I didn't. It should be possible to convert the different values quite easily. But it is unclear how realible these conversions are. At least for my limited set of skills.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the tools don't function the same way, and there isn't a 1-to-1 mapping of LR tools to darktable tools. Your converter could approximate the settings from LR modules, but I don't think you'll ever get 1-to-1 conversion.